# Does JFrog Xray supports ruby gems

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

Does JFrog Xray supports ruby gems at this point? I don't see it listed in the features page https://jfrog.com/xray/features/

If it does't is there a plan to include ruby gems in jfrog xray in the near future ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Xray support for RubyGems will be released by Q2-2018.